# Excel - Wrap range of rows at a given column, with first column repeating for the range of rows

Tags: excel, vba, layout, rows

Technically, the solution I'm looking for is to minimize actual programing. I need to know if there is Excel functionality I can invoke from VBA, instead of having to code the entire logic myself.

Imagine the following sheet:

```
Position   Competency1 Competency2 Competency3 Competency4
Employee1      x                                    x 
Employee2      x                        x
```

What I need is the following result:

```
Position   Competency1 Competency2
Employee1      x                  
Employee2      x                  

Position   Competency3 Competency4
Employee1                   x                  
Employee2      x
```

In other words, I want Excel to move the columns down, but maintain the first column. Now for the complicated bit; there will be several positions, with various employees. So a final product might look like:

```
Position   Competency1 Competency2
Employee1      x                  
Employee2      x                  

Position   Competency3 Competency4
Employee1                   x                  
Employee2      x                  

Position2  Competency5 
Employee3      x                              
Employee4
```

The data is fetched from a database and formatted into the above layout via VBA. The amount of positions and employees/competencies per position are all variable.

I can of course code the entire thing, but it would make my life a lot easier if I could just throw some parameters at Excel and have it do it for me. Problem is, what relevant functionality I've found appears to be sheet-wide, while I need to be able to specify multiple sets of rows and columns.

I rather suspect the answer is: "Suck it up and code it". But I don't know enough Excel to say for sure.

Comment: In this case I recommend a PivotTable, and you don't even need to write code to create it.

Comment: I have not been able to sort this out using PivotTable and none of my colleagues can see how it could be done either. If it is indeed possible, it seems likely I would use as much or even more time figuring out how and preparing the data than just coding it in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the first list will be Position with Employees down the bottom. And that no other lists are there. Assuming this: here is logically what you need to code

1. numberOfColumns: Count the cells going down where the cell is not blank in column A (the position column) minus 1. This will give the number of employees (excluding the Position cell).
2. numberOfRows: Count the number of cells going across (row 1). This will be the number of Competency cells minus 1 (excluding the Position cell).
3. competancyColumns : Define a variable capturing how many competency columns they need for each position. This can be through a textbox or in a cell on another sheet or something e.g. a value of 2
4. Start at A1 + competancyColumns. Copy and cut cells after to end of row.
5. Start at A1 + numberOfRows + 1. Add another counter to keep track of position (counter) so after point 4 the counter should read 2 (0 + competancyColumns).
   Paste cells (from point 4)

Repeat process until the counter = numberOfcolumns. Obviously not starting at A1 but the row you were at.

You can store it in an Array if you don't want to use Cut and Paste, but thats for you to decide.

SO that should be the basic logic.

Comment: I don't have any technical issues coding it, it's the time aspect of it I am trying to avoid. There's a lot of VBA code there already (the sheet is populated via VBA from data on several other sheets which are again populated from a database), and it's not very maintenance friendly. It would be quicker and more robust if Excel had functionality that would solve it for me in an uncomplicated fashion.

Based on the replies, I am going to go with my original assumption of there not being a simple way to have Excel handle this sort of thing for me and just code it.

Comment: Excel is not that advanced. It cannot conjure up solutions to every single problem. What you are asking for is not difficult, and is quite easy to implement within Excel. VBA is the only option for you if you want to automate it.

Comment: It would not be a terribly advanced feature compared to some that are already present, but it clearly does not exist. I ended up modifying the existing code to split the lines as needed while populating.